# Java- Android Toast Message doesn't show me me the message

Tags: java, android-studio, android-toast

I'am new to Android Studio, here is my problem, i used some other solutions but they were not useful. i don't know what is the problem with that.

Code is given below,

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etName;
    EditText etEmail;
    EditText etPass;

    RadioButton radioButton1;
    RadioButton radioButton2;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

       Button sgButton = findViewById(R.id.sgButton);
       etEmail = findViewById(R.id.input_Email);
       etPass = findViewById(R.id.input_password);
       etName = findViewById(R.id.inputName);

       radioButton1 = findViewById(R.id.f);
       radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.m);

       radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        sgButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                        final String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

                       Toast toast  =  Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,
                                "Crunch you felt it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,0);
                       toast.show();  // here is the Code for Toast.


                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any `Exception` or does the `Toast` just not show up?
Try `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Crunch you felt it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`.

Comment: No exception, i just tried (getApplicationContext(),
                                "Crunch you felt it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); ) , But no toast is showing.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Crunch you felt it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
try this, @deHaar forgot to give show().

Comment: Don't you ´show()´ it two lines below? But ok, if it has to be appended to make it ´Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Crunch you felt it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(), do it like that. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes it work now, thanks guys!